# Combine box shadow with a signed distance field

Tags: glsl, 2d, unity, signed-distance-field

I'm using 2d signed distance fields in my current project for drawing shapes (example: https://www.shadertoy.com/view/4llXD7) and I want to add drop shadows to them. At first I thought I could exploit the sdfs distance property to achieve good enough looking drop shadows, but I found that in many cases this left undesirable results in the interior of the shapes where there is often a darker 'x' in center.

I found this shadertoy https://www.shadertoy.com/view/tdSGDc which is produces exactly what I am looking for in terms of quality and performance, but I can't seem to figure out how I would combine this 1d box blur effect with arbitrary sdf shapes to achieve a nice looking drop shadow. Is there a way I can combine these two techniques to get great looking shadows?

Comment: Hi. Please consider editing more information into your question so that it can be understood without he links which might expire some day.

Comment: I had a similar issue: Wasn't able to fully solve this cause there is a max blur state I reach for some reason, but at least the x is gone: https://github.com/Haeri/ElementalDraw/blob/master/data/shader/gl/rounded_rect.frag
This is how it looks:
https://github.com/Haeri/ElementalDraw/tree/master/examples/overview

Comment: Thanks Haeri I'll take a look, I've actually stumbled across your project before, cool stuff!